# How to find a substring in a string in PHP

Tags: php

I want to find a string within a string, for instance:

```
  abcbabababbbacc  //Initial string
```

And I have to find if it contains `abc` or not, if yes then replace it with other characters. I have written this code:

```
 $check = false;
    if(strpos($set, "abc"))
    {
        $set = preg_replace("abc", "aab", $set);
        $check = true;
    }

    return $check;
```

But I get `false` in output always. Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: Because `abc` is at the first position of your string `strpos()` will return zero, which is intepreted as `false`. You should use `if (strpos($set, "abc") === false)` to test that is realy `false`.

Comment: Questions like that one are the reason why there is already [a big red "warning" box in the documentation on `strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php). Now it would be fine if beginners start reading those docs…

Comment: Additionally your `preg_replace` is invalid. Regex in PHP require delimiters. Also if you don't need a regex (which in this case you dont because you arent doing anything special with it) don't use one, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $check = false;
    if(strpos($set, "abc") !== false)// you need to chage
    {
        $set = preg_replace("abc", "aab", $set);
        $check = true;
    }

    return $check;
```

Comment: Could you explain more about what your code does? (from review)